# RxJs in full stack Kotlin/JS

Tags: kotlin, rxjs, kotlin-js

I'm having difficulty importing the RxJs library in my full stack Kotlin/JS project. I put the following in my `build.gradle.kts` file in the `frontendMain` section:

```
implementation(npm("@reactivex/rxjs", "6.6.7", true))
```

But when I try to add a declaration in a class:

```
val mySub = Subject<String>()
```

IntelliJ isn't able to find the import to use. I'm new at this and am obviously missing something simple. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you can't call JS from Kotlin without `external class Subject` etc.